# SQL Linked Server Connection Works with Windows Authenticatoin on Server but not on Workstation

Tags: sql, linked-server, visual-foxpro

I have a virtual desktop which is hosting a SQL Server 2014 32 bit intance named "MyRemoteServer". The server has been set up with a linked server named "mscribe" using VFPOLEDB which is the OLEDB for FOXPro.

When I am logged directly into the virtual desktop I am able to query the linked server in SSMS by connecting with either Windows Authentication or a SQL Account. However when I access the server using SSMS from my laptop, the SQL Account is able to query the linked server without a problem, but when using Windows Authentication the same query returns an error. I have also tried formatting this as an openquery however I get the same error. What confuses me further about this is that I have another linked server (this one is a remote SQL Server) setup on MyRemoteServer and when I connect from my laptop using Windows Authentication I have no problems querying it.

Query:

```
Select o.ordernr from mscribe...[order] o where o.ordernr = 'O12345'
```

Error:

> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "VFPOLEDB" for linked server "mscribe".

With this error and the fact that I can query the other linked server my first assumption would be that the issue is with the setup of the linked server, however since the same query works when executed using the SQL Account I must assume that this is not the issue. My next assumption would be a permissions issue, however the Windows Authentication works when I am logged directly into the Server so I am not sure that this is the issue either.

Any help or suggestions are very much appreciated.

Thank You